# Function does not wait until Promise is resolved

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I'm developing a simple discord bot and I am attempting to print some general data about a certain player. I recently learned about async/await and I attempted to implement it into my code. It does not seem to work however because when I first trigger this code, it prints null but on subsequent triggers it will print the correct data, indicating that my function did not wait for the Promise to resolve.

```
async function stats(){
    data = await NBA.stats.playerInfo({ PlayerID: curry.playerId });
}

 stats();  

 data = JSON.stringify(data);
 console.log(data);
```

The variable data is a global variable declared at the top of my program and initially initialized to null.

Comment: `await NBA.stats.playerInfo` what are you expecting to happen here? What does the `playerInfo` method return?

Comment: Ok so I am very new to nodejs and this is the package I am using.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nba

It is supposed to be returning a Promise. In it is just data such a players last name, first name, birthday etc.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the output. 

https://imgur.com/38v3asL

Comment: Your function awaits correctly, but you don't await your function before trying to use it. You would need to `await stats();`

Comment: @Paulpro that's incorrect, you can only use `await` within an `async` function. `await stats()` won't work unless the entire code snippet were to be wrapped inside another `async` function

Comment: @AakashJain What I said is completely correct. Obviously to `await stats();` the function stats is called from must also be `async`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, what you want is to asynchronously fetch some data into `data` and then display it on the console.

Your implementation of `stats` is doing the fetch correctly. But your problem is, the part where you log to console has no dependence on the fetch being completed.

When you call a function that has been declared `async`, you are saying that you want it to execute "in the background" so to speak. The interpreter won't wait for that function to finish executing.

```
stats(); // begin executing this function

data = JSON.stringify(data); // but don't wait for it to finish before moving on to this line
console.log(data);
```

Clearly, that's not what you want. Instead, you want to wait for `stats` to finish what it's doing before logging `data`. `stats` being an async function returns a Promise, so you can do this:

```
function logData() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

stats().then(logData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Aakash. This solution works and I understand why it works and where I went wrong.