# Problem when I try to get collection from Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After seeing all the answers, I edited the code again. But I still have a problem

```
const getPosts = async () => {
const snapshot = await firestore.collection('posts').get();
const posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data() }));

return posts; };


const PostsList = () => {
let postsData = null;
getPosts().then((posts) => {
    postsData = posts;
}); 

console.log(postsData); // null
return postsData.map((post) => <PostItem key={post.id} event={post} />); };
```

Answer (score 3):

You have introduced asynchronous code here.

```
firestore.collection(`posts`).get().then((snapShot) => {
        snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            let data = { ...doc.data() };
            posts.unshift(data);
        });
    });
```

The get() method returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which will be handled inside .then() method once it gets resolved. That means, only the contents inside the then() will wait for its execution to finish and any thing outside of the block will be executed synchronously.

In your case, all console.log() methods will get executed before you actually get data from the Fire base. To fix it you can either manipulate the data inside the then() method like [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7015400/peter-haddad) said or you can make use of [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Example:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});

const consoleIt = async () => { // returns a promise implicitly
  value = await promise1;
  console.log('value',value)
}
consoleIt(); // Expected output: "value" "foo"

//or

const consoleIt2 = async () => { // returns a promise implicitly
  value = await promise1;
  return value;
}
consoleIt2().then(value => console.log('value', value)); // Expected output: "value" "foo"
```

Your code should be:

```
const getPosts = async () => {
    const posts = [];
    let snapShot = await firestore.collection(`posts`).get(); // rest of the code will wait for the snapShot value.
    snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            let data = { ...doc.data() };
            posts.unshift(data);
        });
    console.log(posts);  
    console.log(posts.length);  
    console.log(posts[1]);  // Will print the object.
    return posts;
};
```

Async functions usually returns promise. You can call this function like

`const posts = await getPosts();`
or 
`getPosts().then((posts)=> {console.log(posts)})`

Your code should be like this

```
const PostsList = () => {
getPosts().then((posts) => {
 console.log(posts); // prints object
 return posts.map((post) => <PostItem key={post.id} event={post} />); };
}); 

// or if you want to handle no data.
let posts = null;
const PostsList = () => {
getPosts().then((res) => {
post = res;
 console.log(posts); // prints object
});
return posts? posts.map((post) => <PostItem key={post.id} event={post} />) : <NoData/>; 
}
```

**NOTE : await keyword should only be used inside an async function!**

Comment: whene i return the posts object, its undefined :(

Comment: in the end of the function 
return posts

new func() {
   const posts = getPosts();
   console.log(posts); // undefined 
}

Comment: Can you setup a code sandbox, so that I can check where the issue is :)
https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Or update the the question with your recent changes and also add the json data you are getting from firebase. With that I can mock the execution and find the flaw.

Comment: const posts = getPosts(); 
console.log(posts); // I think that this line executes immediately and will not wait for getPosts to return value.
are the console.log() functions inside getPosts function printing values?

Comment: use either await or use then() for it to complete. 
use 
const posts =  await getPosts();

Comment: can you write how to wrap something in a promise?

Comment: let postsData = null;
 getPosts().then((posts) => {
  postsData = posts;
 });

 console.log(postsData); // null

Comment: let postsData = null; getPosts().then((posts) => { postsData = posts; }); console.log(postsData);
this will repeat the the same problem. console.log(postsData) will print undefined since it won't wait for the getPost() function call to be resolved. You should use await or you should move console.log(postsData)  inside then() function

Comment: I have updated the promise example to suite your situation. Let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: please see my updated post, how do i get the posts data into my <PostItem /> component?

Comment: Move the return statement into getPosts.then() function, so that it will wait for the promise to get resolved.

Comment: i did exactly as you sad - but i get an error "Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Comment: If then() function is not executed at any point (since we did not catch errors), the return will not be executed. So I have updated the answer again. See if it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204791/discussion-between-karthick-b-and-yuda-zvi).

Answer (score 2):

`get()` returns a `Promise`, which is used for asynchronous code.

> The `then()` method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

Therefore the `console.log(posts);` outside the `then` method will return undefined since the data is not retrieved yet. You need to do the following:

```
const getPosts = () => {
    const posts = [];
    firestore.collection(`posts`).get().then((snapShot) => {
        snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            let data = { ...doc.data() };
            posts.unshift(data);
            console.log(posts);    
            console.log(posts[1]);

        });
    });
};
```

If you want to access the array outside the `then()` method then you can return a `Promise`:

```
const getPosts = () => {
    const posts = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
  firestore.collection(`posts`).get().then((snapShot) => {
        snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            let data = { ...doc.data() };
            posts.unshift(data);
            console.log(posts); 
            resolve(posts);  
            console.log(posts[1]);

        });
    });
   });
};
```

Then you can do the following:

```
getPosts().then((posts) => {
   console.log(posts);
 });
```

Check the following links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: but i want to use the data outside of this function

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: let postsArr = null;
 getPosts().then((posts) => {
  postsArr = posts;
 });

 console.log(postsArr); // null

Comment: thanks, but i cant find a solution there. i need to get the data out of a function and into a simple const

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend in general to avoid mutating the array using push. That said, you could return the posts from the function so it is easier to work with them

```
const getPosts = async () => {
    const snapshot = await firestore.collection('posts').get();
    return snapshot.docs.map(snap => Object.assign({}, { ...snap.data() }))
}
```

The await keyword will delay the execution of the code that depends on "snapshot" until the Promise is resolved.

EDIT
I put it in its original form again as it is concise and readable. The problem is that the getPost func should be awaited too, because if you do something like:

```
const posts = getPosts()
```

It would be used immediately and not wait for the getPost() to finish. You can use a .then if you want in getPosts, e.g:

```
getPosts().then(result => console.log(result))
```

You could also wrap the function that uses the getPosts() in an async/await and be able to use its results as it were a sync function.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348886/function-does-not-wait-until-promise-is-resolved) for a related question and another explanation, and also fo the other answers in this same question.

Comment: it return a promise not an object

Comment: I edited my answer. It should return now an array of objects

Comment: its still returns a promise

Comment: @YudaZvi I saw your edit on the response (can't add a comment due to lack of rep). Why you initialize postData as null? If you initialize it as an empty array your code will work flawlessly